# How to ensure that specific string can be converted to SolidBrush in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF there is brush converter so you can convert from string to exact type:

```
var converter = new BrushConverter();
BorderBrush = converter.ConvertFromString("Red") as SolidColorBrush
```

In case string is invalid then exception will be thrown.

How to verify (besides try catch which is not elegant) conversion can be done?

I know converter has build in function CanConvert but I did not found proper example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the IsValid method :

```
if(converter.IsValid("red")
{
     borderBrush = converter.ConverterFromString("red") as SolidColorBrush;
}
```